# ASP.Net Web Application Localhost Refused to Connect after Save

Tags: asp.net, localhost, iis-7.5

I am writing my first ASP.net Web Application using VS2015 and IIS 7.5.  After I make changes in the code and save, I right click and hit View in Browser to see the page.  A new tab opens in Chrome and the page comes up fine, but when I go back to the aspx page and make some changes and resave, when I try and refresh the browser tab that opened earlier I get 'This Site Can't be Reached Localhost refused to connect'.  I then have to go back to VS and right click and View in Browser again which opens a new tab and the page works.  Is there anyway to keep the original tab that opened persistent so I can just refresh it to show code changes?  It's a bit tedious having to open a new tab for every change.  Thanks.

Edit: seems to be a timeout issue as it doesn't matter if I make changes at all.  Trying to refresh the browser after 20 or so seconds causing the connection refused error.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I have an asp:repeater that builds a table.  The table had over 4000 rows in it.  When I removed the table or when I reduced the rows to under 300 I was able to refresh the page as many time as I want.  As soon as I bumped the rows back up to 4000 the issue came back.  Not sure why the amount of data was an issue though.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools-Options

Under Projects and solution -> Build

Run select "Always build" under "On Run, when projects are out of date"